# mysql_insert_id() for INSERT...SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I am doing similar INSERT...SELECT query to this

```
INSERT INTO table (value1, value2) 
SELECT 'stuff for value1', 'stuff for value2' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table
      WHERE value1='stuff for value1' AND value2='stuff for value2') 
LIMIT 1
```

, where table has auto-genrated id.

And I would like to know if it was inserted or not, of course. I assume the way to do that is to use `mysql_insert_id()`. It returns 0 if no insertions happen and 1 if insertions happen. Looking more details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-insert-id.html).

> If an INSERT ... SELECT statement is executed, and **NO** automatically
>   generated value is successfully inserted, mysql_insert_id() **RETURNS**
>   the ID of the last inserted row.

What does it return if no auto-generated ID was successfully inserted? Is this a doc typo?

**UPDATE1**

So far I did testing in C and `mysql_insert_id()` returns always 0 if insertion did not happen even if the last insertion succeeded and `mysql_insert_id()` returned non-zero result. A paragraphs in the same manual, mentioned above, confirms this behavior by saying:

> mysql_insert_id() returns 0 if the previous statement does not use an AUTO_INCREMENT value. ....
>
> The value of mysql_insert_id() is affected only by statements issued within the current client connection. It is not affected by statements issued by other clients.
>
> The LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function will contain the value of the first automatically generated value that was successfully inserted. LAST_INSERT_ID() is not reset between statements because the value of that function is maintained in the server. ....

And that feels kind of logical otherwise `INSERT...SELECT` would be useless in many cases, if you cannot know within the code if your insertion worked or not. But it totally contradicts to the statement above. Did anyone have experience with this?

**UPDATE2**

From MariaDB manual, also suggests that the value should be zero in case of insertion did not happen:

> The mysql_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query on
>   a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute or the value
>   for the last usage of LAST_INSERT_ID(expr). If the last query wasn't
>   an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a
>   column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute and LAST_INSERT_ID was not
>   used, this function will return zero.

Comment: Exactly as it reads ..  If the insert fails for whatever reason other than an error --  It will get the last inserted id -- That last inserted id can be something that was inserted yesterday, last week .. whenever .. Just the **previously** successful, last insert id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysql_affected_rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) is your friend. It will be greater than 0, if you successfully inserted rows (except when it returns (my_ulonglong)-1, which indicates failure). In your case, since you insert at most 1 row, you just need to check whether it returned 1.

Comment: Thank you for a hint. So you suggest to call `mysql_affected_rows` first, and then if it is `1` call `mysql_insert_id`, right? Because I need an id if an insertion happen.

Comment: That seems like an option. But do you know anything about `mysql_insert_id` for insert...select? Why the doc is so confusing? And if the MySQL doc is correct why it is not mentioned in MariaDB?

Comment: I do not know why MySQL docs are so confusing, you can ask them for clarification. Those things (affected rows, last_insert_id) are sent as to the client via MySQL protocol, packed in "OK packet". On any update statement, whether INSERT( with or without SELECT), UPDATE or DELETE.  I really recommend just do the same thing for insert/select as you would for any update  -i.e check for success (are there any affected rows), then retrieve your ID.

Comment: That's the best answer, and btw, this information can be available without any additional query according to language/driver. Example for java : int affectedRows = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO <table> (select ...)");

Answer (score 3):

The wording could be more clear, but what it means is that if your INSERT causes an error, mysql_insert_id() (or the SQL function `last_insert_id()`) continues to report whatever it did based on an earlier *successful* INSERT.

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> create table foo( id int auto_increment primary key);
mysql> create table bar( id int primary key);    
mysql> insert into bar (id) values (1), (2), (10);

mysql> insert into foo select id from bar;

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
```

No new auto-inc values were generated, because my INSERT gave specific values to insert.

Let's generate some new values:

```
mysql> insert into foo select null from bar;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|               11 |
+------------------+
```

This is expected, because last_insert_id() will report the *first* id generated by a batch insert. You have to do the math to figure out how many rows were inserted, so you can know the rest of the id's. The id's generated in this way are guaranteed to be unique and consecutive.

Now let's try inserting some duplicates, which will cause an error:

```
mysql> insert into foo select id from bar;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Now comes the point of the sentence in the documentation: there has been no change in what last_insert_id() reports.

```
mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|               11 |
+------------------+
```

Likewise, even if the INSERTs are successful, but do not cause any new auto-inc values to be generated, there is no change in what last_insert_id() reports.

```
mysql> insert into foo select id+20 from bar;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|               11 |
+------------------+
```

Many people assume last_insert_id() reports the most recent primary key value inserted, but it doesn't. It only reports values that were generated automatically by the auto-inc feature.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it will return the id that was last auto-generated:

```
MariaDB [stackoverflow]> desc a;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| a     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| b     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [stackoverflow]> insert into a(a,b) values('haha', 'haha');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
MariaDB [stackoverflow]> select LAST_INSERT_ID() from dual;
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+

MariaDB [stackoverflow]> insert into a(a,b) select 'hi', 'hello' from dual;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [stackoverflow]> select LAST_INSERT_ID() from dual;
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [stackoverflow]> insert into a(a,b) select 'hi', 'hello' from dual where not exists (select * from a where a='hi' and b='hello') limit 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [stackoverflow]> select LAST_INSERT_ID() from dual;
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```